# Could not find ABCpdf license

Tags: asp.net, abcpdf

I've been using ABCPdf for a while. I originally installed it via the installer and plugged the license in during the installation. But now I'm adding the dll via Nuget so that I can build my solution in the cloud using MSBuild. And now I get the following love letter...

```
Could not find ABCpdf license. Attempt to insert license failed. Please see Manual Installation section of documentation.
```

[Here](https://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/default.htm?page=source%2F3-concepts%2F6-installation.htm) it says do this...

```
XSettings.InstallLicense("cd9b5c07db69df2bf57c0a04d9bca58b10c44889c9fb197984e592f49addfce5ec5fe85d7b9205bc")
```

I added this line in on application start (although my usage of ABCPdf is in a different project) and I get the same error. Also, my license key doesn't look like this neat, single line of numbers and letters. It was supplied across multiple lines and looks base64 encoded.

Any ideas how to install the license when using Nuget installation?

Answer (score 2):

The `XSettings.InstallLicense` call is correct.
If you combine all the lines of your license into one line and take everything between the square brackets, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I used an assembly redirect in web.config to point to the older version of the dll that was installed in the GAC. lol.